# bootstrap collapse content panel should be activated on mobile device

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem to activate collapse content panel over mobile devices and on desktop it should be de-activated. I've used bootstrap collapse feature.

Comment: hi @jatin on what display size you want to activate collapse panel

Comment: when resolution size less then 767px

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use this jquery code. it will help you. working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sunnysm/2zoh1ujb/3/) example

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($(window).width() < 767){  
    $('.panel-collapse').removeClass('in');
    $('.panel-collapse:first').addClass('in');
    $('.collapsed').css({'pointer-events':'auto','cursor':'pointer'});
  }else{
    $('.panel-collapse').addClass('in');
    $('.collapsed').css({'pointer-events':'none','cursor':'default'});
  }
});
```